# Firebase Cloud Function downloading almost 100Kb each time?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, my database is set up such that there are posts, conversations, and postDetails.

```
"posts" : {
"-LG57gaS08hS8WsuU6j2" : {
  "Revealed" : "true",
  "datePosted" : "2018-06-28 11:24:02 +0000",
  "key" : "GCrjH2E3pDuW7dEGl8",
  "post" : "Lolllyooo",
  "poster" : "CAD54A563CAB99107D9BBDB7F2234FA3",
  "revealedDate" : 1530185042340,
  "reveals" : 0,
  "revealsRequired" : 3,
  "timeOfDeletion" : 1530271442340,
  "watchedBy" : {
    "BmVot3XHEpYwMNtiucWSb8XPPM42" : "false",
    "Ih5m9VUnJnewKvqiZCVgBFwCFrz1" : "false",
    "NMo1gUPKWFcdhsrnCbKte7JfrcA2" : "false",
    "dlwFYqlu2mgetB5zO6TNmFGBWcb2" : "false"
  }
}
```

Poster information:

```
"posters" : {
"-LFzT4c6ylIcPne9F7QS" : {
  "posterID" : "BmVot3XHEpYwMNtiucWSb8XPPM42",
  "posterName" : "Jibran Khalil",
  "profileImage" : "nil"
}
```

Conversations:

```
"conversations" : {
"-LFzccEzciNPSTFAZAhb" : {
  "49C91D37EE1C4B3E07FE24FEBE9ED72B" : "true",
  "CAD54A563CAB99107D9BBDB7F2234FA3" : "true",
  "Date" : "2018-06-27 05:06:12 +0000",
  "convoID" : "-LFzccEzciNPSTFAZAhb",
  "created_at" : 1.5300759725991712E9,
  "last_message" : "lesseee",
  "last_message_time" : 1530077715525,
  "postID" : "-LFzT4c6ylIcPne9F7QS",
  "status" : "sent",
  "timeOfDeletion" : 1530159609351
},
```

When a post's revealed status is changed from false to true, a cloud function is run that collects the post's information and appends it to the post, as such:

```js
 exports.checkIfRevealNumberIsEnough = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postIDthatWasRevealed}/Revealed').onUpdate((event) => {
const revealedValue = event.data.val()

if (revealedValue === "true") {
    var updates = {}
    const postID = event.params.postIDthatWasRevealed
    const revealedConnection = admin.database().ref('/posts/'+postID).once('value', (snapshot) => {
        const postDetails = snapshot.val()
        const key = postDetails["key"]
        const watchedBy = postDetails["watchedBy"]
        const posterDetailsReference = admin.database().ref('/posters/'+ postID).once('value', (snapshot) => {

            const posterDetails = snapshot.val()
            const posterID = posterDetails.posterID
            const posterName = posterDetails.posterName
            var posterPic = ''
            if (posterDetails.profileImage) {
                 posterPic = posterDetails.profileImage
            }
            else {
                 posterPic = "nil"
            }

            const currentTime= Date.now()
            const addedTime = currentTime + 172800000

            updates["/posts/"+postID+"revealedDate"] = currentTime
            updates["/posts/"+postID+"timeOfDeletion"] = addedTime
            updates["/posts/"+postID+"/information/posterID"] = posterID
            updates["/posts/"+postID+"/information/posterName"] = posterName
            updates["/posts/"+postID+"/information/profileImage"] = posterPic

            for (var child in watchedBy) {
                if (watchedBy[child] !== "false") {

                    const conversationID = watchedBy[child]

                    updates["/conversations/"+conversationID+"/information/reciever/Name"] = posterName
                    updates["/conversations/"+conversationID+"/information/reciever/profileImage"] = posterPic
                    updates["/conversations/"+conversationID+"key"] = key

                }
            }

    });
    });

    return admin.database().ref().update(updates)

}
else {
    return null
}
});
```

The data download usage should not be too massive, as I only download the post's information from the posters child and the post itself - maybe a few hundred bytes, or a small number of kilobytes, *at most*. Instead, the database profile run in my terminal, when the function runs, show that all the children in the database are being read and that 87 kb are downloaded, as such:

Downloaded Bytes

┌──────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ Path                                     │ Total    │ Count │ Average  │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /                                        │ 87.99 kB │ 6     │ 14.67 kB │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /posts/-LG57kMo35XkrfCmVIGA              │ 438 B    │ 2     │ 219 B    │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /posts/-LG57kMo35XkrfCmVIGA/Revealed     │ 99 B     │ 2     │ 49.5 B   │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /posters/-LG57kMo35XkrfCmVIGA            │ 93 B     │ 1     │ 93 B     │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /posts/-LG57gaS08hS8WsuU6j2/watchedBy    │ 0 B      │ 1     │ 0 B      │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /posts/-LG57kMo35XkrfCmVIGA/watchedBy    │ 0 B      │ 1     │ 0 B      │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /posts/-LG5Bxy5otbLgs-p43co/watchedBy    │ 0 B      │ 1     │ 0 B      │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /posters/-LG5Bxy5otbLgs-p43co            │ 0 B      │ 1     │ 0 B      │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /posts/-LG57gaS08hS8WsuU6j2              │ 0 B      │ 1     │ 0 B      │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /posts/-LG5Bxy5otbLgs-p43co              │ 0 B      │ 1     │ 0 B      │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /reveals/-LFzJVQyQiDwTPMLTMlC            │ 0 B      │ 1     │ 0 B      │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /reveals/-LFzK2M1Tu5c2PJTfyxu            │ 0 B      │ 1     │ 0 B      │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /reveals/-LFzT4c6ylIcPne9F7QS            │ 0 B      │ 1     │ 0 B      │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /reveals/-LFzd-uN4kRfU18TBj0N            │ 0 B      │ 1     │ 0 B      │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /shortNames/NnB8iVzVOAg5gYtt5FAzLYuuaDO2 │ 0 B      │ 1     │ 0 B      │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /users/$wildcard                         │ 0 B      │ 26    │ 0 B      │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /messages                                │ 0 B      │ 1     │ 0 B      │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /posters                                 │ 0 B      │ 1     │ 0 B      │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /posts                                   │ 0 B      │ 2     │ 0 B      │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /reveals                                 │ 0 B      │ 1     │ 0 B      │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /shortNames                              │ 0 B      │ 1     │ 0 B      │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│ /users                                   │ 0 B      │ 1     │ 0 B      │
└──────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────┴───────┴──────────┘

Furthermore, there are no listed unindexed queries. I have tried to minimize the amount of data being download by minimizing references, and yet there is massive data downloaded and *84 operations* recorded when the cloud function is run. What could be going on? Is the conversations update incorrect? How can I reduce the data download usage and for what reasons is it downloading almost 100 kilobytes on each invocation?

[image: Image of data download usage]

UPDATE: Additionally, there is a cron job run every minute. Could this be the possible culprit? There is only one reference and it uses once and not on value.

```js
    exports.hourly_job = functions.pubsub.topic('hourly-tick').onPublish((event) => {
  const currentTime = Date.now()
  const getPostsForDate = admin.database().ref('posts').orderByChild('timeOfDeletion').endAt(currentTime); 
  return getPostsForDate.once('value', (snapshot) => {
        var updates = {};
        var convoUpdates = {};

        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {

            const postDetails = childSnapshot.val();
            const postIDtoDelete = childSnapshot.key
            const peopleWatching = postDetails["watchedBy"]
            console.log(peopleWatching)
            updates[postIDtoDelete] = null

            for (var childKey in peopleWatching) {
                let value = peopleWatching[childKey]
                if (value !== "false") {
                    convoUpdates[value] = null
                }
            }

                })

            admin.database().ref('posts').update(updates)
            admin.database().ref('conversations').update(convoUpdates)
        })
  });
```

[image: Another huge data download with only the two cloud functions running.]

Comment: It looks like you should be using [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once) instead of `on()` to fetch data.  `on()` leaves the listener attached--almost never correct for a Cloud Function.

Comment: @BobSnyder okay, I'll change that. Is there any reason why the database profile has so many operations being run and that the data usage is showing references to children that were never accessed?

Comment: @BobSnyder I edited the question to include the other cloud function running. I attempted to minimize download requests but it still remains that occasionally the database profiler shows 44 kilobytes or 80 kilobytes downloaded, when in fact the entire JSON file of the database exported is only 35 kilobytes!

Answer (score 1):

Add an index for `posts` on `timeOfDeletion`:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ...
    "posts": {
      ".indexOn": ["timeOfDeletion"]
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Currently, I have it as "posts": {
      ".indexOn": "timeOfDeletion"
    } without square brackets. Will adding that make a difference? Also, does it take time for the database to index as I added the index only a few hours ago.

Comment: Not sure.  Don't see a clear example in [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#indexon).

Comment: Thanks for the help - I'll try and waiting and test in a few hours and test how much data the functions are consuming. Hopefully it will be minimized to one or two kilobytes per invocation.

Comment: Check that `timeOfDeletion` is being set to the correct value.  If they are mistakenly set to some time in the past, the query will fetch all of them.

Comment: they are being set to the right value. When I change the timeOfDeletion to, say for instance, 0, the post deletes as it should. Thus, the query is properly getting the correct child posts as the rest of the posts remain undeleted. I tried the database profiler again and still, there's 44 kilobytes of data being downloaded for the path /. It's showing a count of 4, and no name after the backslash - just /.